# PHP replace text based on text from file

Tags: php, text, replace

i have textfile.txt:

```
aaa
bbb
...
zzz
```

i want remove some text based on text from textfile.txt

```
ex: we have aaa files ==> we have files
```

my codes still not work :

```
<?php
$fp = @fopen("textFile.txt", 'r'); 
$array = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize("textFile.txt")));

if (isset($_POST['btcari'])){    
    print_r(str_ireplace($array,"", $_POST['tateks']));
}
?>
```

thanks vo ur appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$array = file("textFile.txt");

function _trim( &$value, $key ) {
    $value = trim( $value );
}

// remove the newlines and extra spacing
array_walk( $array, '_trim' );

$replaceArray = array_fill( 0, count($array), '' );

if( isset( $_POST[ 'btcari' ] ) ) {
    echo str_replace( $array, $replaceArray, $_POST[ 'tateks' ] );
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First read the file and change text inside it. Then write into file the new content.

```
$fp = @fopen("textFile.txt", 'r'); 
$array = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize("textFile.txt")));
fclose($fp);

foreach($array as $text) {

$textall .= str_replace("aaa", "", $text);

}


$fh = fopen("textFile.txt", "w") or die("Could not open log file.");
fwrite($fh, $textall) or die("Could not write file!");
fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_replace

```
    $replace = "/".$_POST['tateks']."/";
    $array = preg_replace($replace , '' , $array);
    print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using wrong post parameter for replace. I tried the code and if you use $_POST[btcari'] instead of $_POST['tateks'], it works fine.

```
<?php
$fp = @fopen("textFile.txt", 'r'); 
$array = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize("textFile.txt")));

if (isset($_POST['btcari'])){    
    print_r(str_ireplace($array,"", $_POST['btcari']));
}
?>
```

Now if i send a post parameter named "btcari", it outputs the replaced text correctly.